# OUTER APPLY REMOVE DUPLICATES

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, outer-join, lateral-join

I have used  outer apply to pull the most recent careID and diagnosis date and then used aggregation function to count the total. The code worked, however as soon as I added another join which is:

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblDEFINITIVE_TREATMENT Tr ON Ref.CARE_ID=Tr.CARE_ID
```

I get duplicate care_id in my output. How can I remove duplicate CARE_id without removing this join? I have tried using aliases, however it did not solve the issue.

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.ltblDIAGNOSIS diag1 ON ref.N4_2_DIAGNOSIS_CODE=diag1.DIAG_CODELEFT
JOIN tblDEMOGRAPHICS dem ON ref.PATIENT_ID=dem.PATIENT_IDLEFT
JOIN dbo.tblDEFINITIVE_TREATMENT Tr ON Ref.CARE_ID=Tr.CARE_IDLEFT
JOIN dbo.ltblDEFINITIVE_TYPE Def ON Tr.TREATMENT=Def.TREAT_CODE



OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1  N4_1_DIAGNOSIS_DATE, diag1.CARE_ID
             FROM DIAGNOSIS diag1
             WHERE ref.CARE_ID=diag1.CARE_ID
             ORDER BY N4_1_DIAGNOSIS_DATE  DESC) diag
```

I have tried using aliases, however it did not solve the issue (to remove duplicate CARE_ID)

Comment: The use of ALL CAPS in your title is considered SHOUTING, please edit.

Comment: You don't say what platform you are using which might matter in solving this problem.

Comment: Could  you share the whole query?

Comment: I think this is an XY problem.

Comment: If there are multiple treatments, then it should be multiple rows for the same care_id, no? How do you define a duplicate?

Comment: Please would you simply tell, if there are multiple treatments, from which row you want to get the results? From the last one entered by date, or first one, or don't you care what you get?

Comment: You could move the DEFINITIVE join(s) inside the OUTER APPLY. That's the easiest way to get rid of it

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the whole query which makes it hard to give a good answer.  You also don't say what platform you are using, so I can't use a platform specific answer but here is the problem:

When you join to the table tblDEFINITIVE_TREATMENT you get two rows for each CARE_IDLEFT value.  So the easy way to fix that is to do a group by like this:

Instead of

```
JOIN dbo.tblDEFINITIVE_TREATMENT Tr ON Ref.CARE_ID=Tr.CARE_IDLEFT
```

do

```
JOIN (
   SELECT CARE_IDLEFT, MIN(START_DATE) AS START_DATE, MIN(DELAY_COMMENTS)
   FROM dbo.tblDEFINITIVE_TREATMENT
   GROUP BY CARE_IDLEFT
) Tr ON Ref.CARE_ID=Tr.CARE_IDLEFT
```

Note, I used MIN to pick which value to use for start_Date and delay_comments.  This may not be the best values -- it depends on the business rules for your situation which row to use from this table.